# Cross Validation in Keras

Tags: machine-learning, python, deep-learning, keras, cross-validation

Suppose I would like to train and test the MNIST dataset in Keras.

The required data can be loaded as follows:

```
from keras.datasets import mnist

digits_data = mnist.load_data()
```

Is there any way in keras to split this data into three sets namely: `training_data`, `test_data`, and `cross_validation_data`?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

From the Keras documentation, you can load the data into Train and Test sets like this:

```
(X_train, y_train), (X_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()
```

As for cross validation, you could follow this example from [here](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/issues/1711).

```
from sklearn.model_selection import StratifiedKFold

def load_data():
    # load your data using this function

def create model():
    # create your model using this function

def train_and_evaluate__model(model, data_train, labels_train, data_test, labels_test):
    model.fit...
    # fit and evaluate here.

if __name__ == "__main__":
    n_folds = 10
    data, labels, header_info = load_data()
    skf = StratifiedKFold(labels, n_folds=n_folds, shuffle=True)

    for i, (train, test) in enumerate(skf):
        print "Running Fold", i+1, "/", n_folds
        model = None # Clearing the NN.
        model = create_model()
        train_and_evaluate_model(model, data[train], labels[train], data[test], labels[test])
```

Answer (score 2):

Not in Keras. I normally just use sklearn's `train_test_split` function:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

train, test = train_test_split(data, train_size=0.8)
```

Keras also has [sklearn wrappers](http://keras.io/scikit-learn-api/) that might be useful later on.

Comment: The link for SKLearn wrappers was not as helpful as this possibly:
https://keras.io/api/keras_tuner/tuners/sklearn/#sklearntuner-class